# Smallest positive integer with a rule

Tags: number-theory

Find the smallest positive integer $N$ with the following property: of the three numbers $N,$ $N + 1,$ and $N + 2,$ one of them is divisible by $2^2,$ one of them is divisible by $3^2,$ one of them is divisible by $5^2,$ and one of them is divisible by $7^2.$

I think that the lcm of $2^2$, $3^2$, $5^2$, which is (2*3*5)=90, would be the answer because I feel like the smallest N would be if N is the one that all the numbers are divisible by.

Comment: In your proposed answer, think about what the gcd of $2^{2},3^{2},5^{2}$ is. Note these are all powers of prime numbers, so there is only one possible answer. Maybe you mean to try looking for the lcm (least common multiple) instead of gcd? That could be a good starting point. Also, you are giving 4 properties for 3 integers. Do you mean to say that each integer must satisfy a different property? Try editing your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Oh yes I meant lcm, thanks for telling me.

Comment: The LCM of $2^2, 3^2$ and $5^2$ is $2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2=8100$.  You don't want one number that has all those divisors, you want one number with some of them, the next number with some more, a third number with some more.

Comment: Why have you made such a drastic edit? One that makes your question seemingly meaningless and "orphans" @RossMillikan's accepted answer? I was about to undo your edits but wanted to ask why you did it first. I have also upvoted the answer, as (if I'm not mistaken) this prevents the question from being deleted by the user anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an exercise in the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  One way to satisfy the requirement is to have $$N \equiv 0 \pmod {2^2\cdot 3^2}\\N+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {5^2}\\N+2\equiv 0 \pmod {7^2}$$
There are a number of other ways to assign the divisors.  The theorem says that once you find one solution there will be others at intervals of $2^2\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^2=168100$.  I don't think there is any easy way to figure out how to assign the divisors to get the smallest answer.  The fact that $7^2$ is just about twice $5^2$ is interesting, and I note that $N=48$ satisfies
$$N+1\equiv 0 \pmod {7^2}\\N+2\equiv 0 \pmod {5^2}$$
The solutions for $N$ are then $48+1225k$.  We now need to find $k$ so that $48+1225k$ is a multiple of $36$.  $48$ has a remainder of $12$ on division by $36$ and $1225$ has a remainder of $1$, so $k=24$ will work and $N=48+24\cdot 1225=29448$ is the smallest positive number that satisfies our requirement.